# Why can't Android Studio resolve symbol ViewPager?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-sdk-tools

I'm new to Android and I'm following the Big Nerd Ranch Guide. In the book we are creating a ViewPager to be able to swipe between list-details. For some reason Android Studio doesn't recognise the ViewPager. Look below for the code.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ViewPager;

public class CrimePagerActivity extends Activity {
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

I don't know what to do or what could be wrong? Has this something to do with the Android SDK?

Comment: `ViewPager` is part of the Android Support family of libraries. Which IDE are you using, and have you attached `support-v4` or `support-v13` to your project in that IDE?

Comment: I'm using Android Studio. And I have not attached support-v4 or support-v13 to the project. How can I do that?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make sure you have downloaded the Android Support Repository using the SDK Manager.

Open the build.gradle file and Add the support library to the dependencies section:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
```

change your import to this:

```
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
```

Comment: Actually, the choice of library depends on whether the OP is using native fragments (use `support-v13`) or something else for pages (use `support-v4`).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I just put "testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'" at the end which you in the middle previously. Try to keep it in following sequence in your gradle file.

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```